# $.each only the last element is shown

Tags: json, ajax, django, filter

I'm trying to filter a list with AJAX, I have an issue where the html only shows the last element. I have read a lot of similar SO questions and to no avail. I have variables, so I don't know whats the issue.

```
$("#programme").change(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        var selected_programme = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        url: '{% url "gps_list" %}',
        data: {
          "selected_programme": selected_programme,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
          var json = $.parseJSON(response);
              $.each( json, function( key, values ) {

                  var valname = values.fields.name;
                  var valco = values.fields.country;
                  var valpro = values.fields.programme_type;
                  var valwhat = values.fields.what;

                  console.log(valname, key);
                  console.log(valco);
                  console.log(valpro);
                  console.log(valwhat);

                    $("#names").html(valname);
                    $("#country").html(valco);
                    $("#pro_types").html(valpro);
                    $("#whats").html(valwhat);
              });
          },
          error: function(response) {
            alert("oh no!");
          }
      });
    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2 class="my-4" id="names">
          <small id="country"></small>
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card mb-4">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2 class="card-title" id="pro_types"></h2>
            <p class="card-text" id="whats"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$("#names").html(valname);
$("#country").html(valco);
$("#pro_types").html(valpro);
$("#whats").html(valwhat);
```

you're **overwriting** whatever those elements had in them before. Since you're doing that in a loop, naturally you only see the result of the last write.

You'll need to either:

1. Write to *different* elements, or
2. *Append* rather than replacing (via `append`)

The specifics will depend on your HTML structure.

---

(Now that you've added your HTML.) I would structure it differently. Don't have any row at all (or have a placeholder "loading" row) to start with. Then build rows and append them when you have a response. Something along these lines:

```js
var entryTemplate = 
    '<div>' +
        '<div class="row">' +
            '<div class="col-md-12">' +
                '<h2 class="my-4">' +
                    '<span class="names"></span>' + // *** Made it a span inside the h2
                    '<small class="country"></small>' +
                '</h2>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="row">' +
            '<div class="col-md-12">' +
                '<div class="card mb-4">' +
                    '<div class="card-body">' +
                        '<h2 class="card-title pro_types"></h2>' +
                        '<p class="card-text whats"></p>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>';

function success(response) {
    var json = $.parseJSON(response);
    var container = $("#container");
    container.empty(); // Removes any previous rows
    $.each( json, function( key, values ) {
        var fields = values.fields;
        var entry = $(entryTemplate);
        entry.find(".names").text(fields.name);
        entry.find(".country").text(fields.country);
        entry.find(".pro_types").text(fields.programme_type);
        entry.find(".whats").text(fields.what);
        container.append(entry.children());
    });
}

success(
    '[' +
        '{"fields": {' +
            '"name": "Name 1",' +
            '"country": "Country 1",' +
            '"programme_type": "PT 1",' +
            '"what": "What 1"' +
        '}},' +
        '{"fields": {' +
            '"name": "Name 2",' +
            '"country": "Country 2",' +
            '"programme_type": "PT 2",' +
            '"what": "What 2"' +
        '}},' +
        '{"fields": {' +
            '"name": "Name 3",' +
            '"country": "Country 3",' +
            '"programme_type": "PT 3",' +
            '"what": "What 3"' +
        '}}' +
    ']'
);

setTimeout(function() {
    success(
        '[' +
            '{"fields": {' +
                '"name": "Name 4",' +
                '"country": "Country 4",' +
                '"programme_type": "PT 4",' +
                '"what": "What 4"' +
            '}},' +
            '{"fields": {' +
                '"name": "Name 5",' +
                '"country": "Country 5",' +
                '"programme_type": "PT 5",' +
                '"what": "What 5"' +
            '}},' +
            '{"fields": {' +
                '"name": "Name 6",' +
                '"country": "Country 6",' +
                '"programme_type": "PT 6",' +
                '"what": "What 6"' +
            '}}' +
        ']'
    );
}, 2000);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since my html code looks like that (I just edited) should I use append?

Comment: @endormi - You'll need to change your structure, not least because `country` is **inside** `names`, so `$("#names").html(...)` will wipe out `country`. Same with `whats` and `pro_types`. Do you want to have a row for each result?

Comment: I tried .append, it worked in a way, but I want to display a new card everytime. Now all of them append into the same card

Comment: Yeah, I want to have a row for each result. `Country` was wiped, but `whats` and `pro_types` weren't.

Comment: (Actually, `pro_types` and `whats` aren't a problem.)

Comment: How would I be able to get a new row for each result? I'm a beginner to these types of stuff

Comment: The issue with `.append` is that I don't want to add more content. I want to filter the list based on selection.

Comment: @endormi - I've added an example.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out

Comment: @endormi - I should point out that this sort of thing is exactly what MVC frameworks like React, Angular, Vue, Svelte, etc. help with. I used to do jQuery things like this all the time. Now it feels very awkward by comparison. :-) That is not criticism, you just said you were new, so I thought it was worth pointing you at another way to go. Happy coding!!

Comment: Thanks for the tip! however I need to use jQuery since I'm using Django.